# What method does sphinx4 use for building its grammar?

Tags: xml, bnf, cmusphinx

What method does `sphinx4` use for building its grammar? `XML` or augmented `BNF`?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to accept both. Look at the `src/apps/edu/cmu/sphinx/demo/transcriber/digits.{gram,grmxl}` files in the Sphinx4 source distribution.

Answer (score 0):

`Sphinx4` parses `JSGF` grammar which is in `ABNF` format.

It currently support `SRGS xml` format, but take care. It is not a complete implementation yet, I mean it does not implement all `SRGS` elements and attributes, so you can't actually depend on their current implementation unless you continue it and fill whats left.

Comment: @Castiblanco ... wow, what a big edit you did there, you impressed me, really useful edit!!!